# In Laravel scout elastic search engine join query is not working

Tags: php, elasticsearch, laravel-5

I am working on elastic search using laravel scout; my searching working correctly for relational table, but I got below error for join query.
`Method Laravel\Scout\Builder::with does not exist.`
Joins are working or not working in search. What is other solution for this?

In my model of post model I have written following method. In `toSearchableArray` I have search data from post and user tables (users name).

```
        public function toSearchableArray()
            {
                $array = [
                    'user_id' => $this->user_id,
                    'post' => $this->post,
                ];
                $extra_data = [];
                $extra_data['name'] = $this->user->name;

                return array_merge($array, $extra_data);
            }

            /**
             * Get the index name for the model.
             *
             * @return string
             */
            public function searchableAs()
            {
                return 'posts_index';
            }

            public function user()
            {
                return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
            }
```

In repository I written `public function elasticSearch($search)`, this function to get user and post data. 
            In repository I have written this function, I got error for `with` method.
            I want to show data from post and user tables; how I show it?

```
         public function elasticSearch($search)
            {
                return $this->post->search($search)->with('user')->get();
                //$ss = Post::search($search)->get();
            }
```

Comment: can you tell me how are you calling this function. and also tell me the value for $this

Comment: Post and User are models

    protected $Post;

   
    protected $user;
public function __construct(Post $post, User $user)
    {
        $this->post = $post;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

Comment: I am clear that you have initialized the value in constructor how are you calling the function and what is the value of $this

Comment: you want to say this search method 
$this->post->search($search)->with('user')->get();
this search method is elastic search method which I have written in this format $this->post->search($search)->with('user')->get();  instead of Post::search($search)->with('user')->get();

Comment: Please help me .

Comment: I can only help if I am able to understand the mistake dear.